# jQuery Issue: Running a function through each and picking up the element

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am having an issue running a function via .each, It jQuery doesn't seem to be picking up the element in question via 'this'. Code below: (**Edit:** I am attempting to centre something regardless of screen width absolutely for multiple elements)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.main-feature h1').each(function() {
        centerThis();
    });
    $('.meta-feature h2').each(function() {
        centerThis();
    });
});//doc-rdy
function centerThis(){
    var trackHeight = $(this).height()/2;
    var trackWidth = $(this).width()/2;
    var pxInEmsHeight = Math.floor((trackHeight / 146) * 100) / 100;
    var pxInEmsWidth = Math.floor((trackWidth / 146) * 100) / 100;
    $(this).css({
        "margin-left": -pxInEmsWidth+'em',
        "margin-top": -pxInEmsHeight+'em'
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var trackHeight = $(this).height()/2;
        var trackWidth = $(this).width()/2;
        var pxInEmsHeight = Math.floor((trackHeight / 146) * 100) / 100;
        var pxInEmsWidth = Math.floor((trackWidth / 146) * 100) / 100;
        $(this).css({
            "margin-left": -pxInEmsWidth+'em',
            "margin-top": -pxInEmsHeight+'em'
        });
    });
}//centerThis
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass `this` as an argument to the `centerThis` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.main-feature h1').each(function() {
        centerThis(this);
    });
    $('.meta-feature h2').each(function() {
        centerThis(this);
    });
});//doc-rdy
function centerThis(elem){
    var trackHeight = $(elem).height()/2;
    var trackWidth = $(elem).width()/2;
    var pxInEmsHeight = Math.floor((trackHeight / 146) * 100) / 100;
    var pxInEmsWidth = Math.floor((trackWidth / 146) * 100) / 100;
    $(elem).css({
        "margin-left": -pxInEmsWidth+'em',
        "margin-top": -pxInEmsHeight+'em'
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var trackHeight = $(this).height()/2;
        var trackWidth = $(this).width()/2;
        var pxInEmsHeight = Math.floor((trackHeight / 146) * 100) / 100;
        var pxInEmsWidth = Math.floor((trackWidth / 146) * 100) / 100;
        $(this).css({
            "margin-left": -pxInEmsWidth+'em',
            "margin-top": -pxInEmsHeight+'em'
        });
    });
}//centerThis
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, hole in one! Ill up the vote in 8m :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to give it as a parameter to the function centerThis() you are calling and replace $(this) in the function with the name of the input parameter.